# Objective-C "message sent to deallocated instance 0x5633b0"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I appear to have some overzealous releasing going on in my obj-C app - getting error message

> "-[myobj release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5633b0"

.  I know the class of the object instance causing the problem, but this class is used all over to create many instances.

My thought is I could put some logging in the init method of the class to log whatever "0x5633b0" corresponds to which should help me track down where the instance is being created.

What exactly is the "0x5633b0" and is there any way I can get access to that value in the code to log it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`0x5633b0` is likely the address of object in question (the value of `self`). You can use `NSLog` or `printf` with `%p` to print it.

Comment: That was it - I just needed a way to get the address of the object somehow.  I added:
NSLog(@"INIT %p", self);
to my init method and was able to tell which instance was causing the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add a breakpoint to : "-[_NSZombie methodSignatureForSelector:]" to make your debugger halt when "message sent to deallocated instance..." is logged.

Comment: hey kenji Can you please help in [_NSZombie methodSignatureForSelector: with some sort of example

Answer (score 42):

What worked best for me when I ran into similar problems recently was the following:

1. Under under *Project->Edit Active Executable -> Arguments tab -> Environment* variables section I added and set to `YES` the following variables: `NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled`, `NSZombieEnabled` and `NSDebugEnabled`.
2. Under the Run menu, I selected *Enable Guard Malloc*.

With these settings the debugger provided more hints on what's wrong with my code.

(I found these tips [here](http://loufranco.com/blog/files/debugging-memory-iphone.html))

Good luck,
Ori

Comment: Enable Guard Malloc doesn't work when debugging on a device, at least I can't and this post confirm it: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1572993?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @JeroenEijkhof is right. Guard malloc don't work in device. And they can be enabled in the 'diagnostice' tab, no need to set in env var. But NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled may need to set as env var.

Answer (score 13):

`0x5633b0` is likely the address of the deallocated object (the value of `myobj`). You can use `NSLog` or `printf` with `%p` to print it.

You can also use the instruments profiler to find the deallocated object.

**1. Start the profiler:**

[image]

**2. Select the "Zombies" and start the profiler.**

[image]

**3. Click through the simulator until you hit your "deallocated error case"**

[image]

Comment: Why does the beginning of your answer completely copy @LoganCapaldo's answer?

Comment: I must have copied it and never looked back. Thx for pointing out. I've added some more explanation there.

Comment: Three years later: Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

In the debugger, type `info symbol 0x5633b0` and you'll get some indication as to what object it is. One other thing that might be helpful is `backtrace` which will give you a stack trace. All in all, [this blog entry](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/debugging-tips-for-objective-c.html) has some **great** tips.

Comment: With `lldb` is `image lookup --address 0x1ec4` or the short version `im loo -a 0x1ec4`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add these to environment variables:
`MallocStackLoggingNoCompact 1`

and write in the gdb console:
`info malloc-history <paste-address-here>`

Reference: [here](http://coderslike.us/2009/05/05/finding-freeddeallocated-instances-of-objects/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider [using the NSZombieEnabled flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode).

You will then know what is this deallocated object you're sending a message.

Answer (score -12):

You're not managing your memory properly -- you're calling `release`/`autorelease` on some object more times than you're calling `retain`.  Make sure you're following all of the rules laid out in the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

0x5633b0 is just the address of the memory location at which the object is stored.  One thing you can try to do is to add some code to the `init` method:

```
- (void) init
{
    if(self == (MyClass*)0x5633b0)
        NSLog(@"Allocated object at address 0x5633b0");  // put a breakpoint on this line
    // do rest of init...
}
```

If you have any other `init` methods (e.g. `initWithCoder:`, which is called for objects instantiated from a XIB), make sure to put this snippet in those methods as well.  Put a breakpoint on the `NSLog` line, and then see when it gets hit.  Note that it may get hit several times, if an object is allocated at that address, deallocated, and then another object happens to be reallocated at the same address.  The last hit before the crash is the one you want.

Comment: How do you know the symbol's address beforehand? Isn't it different each time you run the code. At least that's I've noticed. Using something like "info symbol 0xabcdfg" in the debugger console gave me better results than your probosal.