# In a xcode project, how can you check what is of what properties have an object in a given adress?

Tags: xcode, exc-bad-access, alloc

I'm trying to use allocations tool but I don't know how to use it, anyways I think this could be very helpful not only in the try of getting rid of a exc_bad_access

Anyways, I managed to get this:

*** -[NSPathStore2 release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6018e00

That is the instance that makes the exc_bad_access right?
But I don't know what it is and my code is huge... i don't know where to start to check.
I'm on xcode 3.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some ideas in the question [Objective-C "message sent to deallocated instance 0x5633b0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601074/objective-c-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-0x5633b0) which might help you get started, e.g:

> 0x6018e00 is likely the address of object in question (the value of self). You can use NSLog or printf with %p to print it.