# IBAction,button and camera

Tags: xcode, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a button in my interface declared in .h file

```
@interface UserProfileVC : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIButton *camera;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *camera;
-(IBAction)cameraPress:(id)sender;
```

And in my .m file i have:

```
-(IBAction)cameraPress:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
//  [picker setDelegate:self];
    [picker setAllowsEditing:YES];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

But I have this error:

```
*** -[UserProfileVC performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7bc2a40
```

Can someone help me? I can't understand what is the mistake.
Thanks

Comment: have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601074/objective-c-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-0x5633b0).

Comment: Ok I inserted.. and I have seen that method viewDidLoad run 2 times ... Why?

Comment: Now I have:                                                            
`2012-06-09 14:41:08.556 SQL[612:11603] INIT 0x7dac3f0
2012-06-09 14:41:08.557 SQL[612:11603] INIT 0x7da87c0
2012-06-09 14:41:10.475 SQL[612:11603] *** -[UserProfileVC performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7dac3f0 `

Comment: The code shown in ur question is perfect. I want u to show the lines of code u wrote for calling the method `-[UserProfileVC performSelector:withObject:withObject:]`
Edit ur question accordingly.

Comment: I call the class UserProfileVC with this method...
`-(void)showDetails:(id)sender{
 NSLog(@"Annotation Click");
    details= [[UserProfileVC alloc] initWithNibName: @"Details" bundle:nil ];
    details.Nome=note.title;

    addNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:details];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addNavigationController animated:YES];
 
}
`

Answer (score 0):

As per the code from ur last comment,

```
-(void)showDetails:(id)sender{ 
NSLog(@"Annotation Click"); 
details= [[UserProfileVC alloc] initWithNibName: @"Details" bundle:nil ]; 
details.Nome=note.title; 
addNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:details]; 
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addNavigationController animated:YES]; 
}
```

I can suggest you following.
If you look at the `UIViewController` class reference document, you will find below notes

```
presentModalViewController:animated:
```

Presents a modal view managed by the given view controller to the user. (**Deprecated**. Use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.)

So I would suggest you to use `presentViewController:animated:completion`. I dont find it relevant to error "message sent to deallocated instance" but still check if u could solve your problem.

Also I dont know Why u wrote this line

```
addNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:details];
```

If you simply want to show `UserProfileVC` in the current `UINavigationController` then I would suggest you to  remove addNavigationController line & write only

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:details animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: I edited the code as you write, the userprofilevc works the same but it is instanced 2 times.|


`-(void)showDetails:(id)sender{
 NSLog(@"Annotation Click");
    details= [[UserProfileVC alloc] initWithNibName: @"Details" bundle:nil ];
    details.Nome=note.title;
    details.coffeeObj=self.coffeeObj;
    [self presentViewController:details animated:YES completion:NULL]; 

 
}`



As you can see was initiated 2 times
`2012-06-13 11:41:28.146 SQL[11463:11903] INIT 0x4e0b5f40
2012-06-13 11:41:28.156 SQL[11463:11903] INIT 0x4dcfbf40`

Comment: From where u got this log? In which method u put `NSLog`? & whats exactly the problem u have now?

Comment: I have inserted nslog in the viewDidLoad of userprofilevc... The problem was the same from the beginning... I mean the double allocation of user profilevc... In fact

Comment: I have inserted nslog in the viewDidLoad of userprofilevc... The problem was the same from the beginning... I mean the double allocation of user profilevc... In fact these 2 Nslog indicate  the code of two classes